# How to use different python versions with virtualenv

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda, virtualenv

I'm trying to install a different python using `virtualenv`. Please note I'm using windows 10. The solutions that are given on SO did not work for me.

I have created an empty director (environment) on my desktop in which I want to place my virtual environments. So I did a `cd` to `c:\data\FFFF\Desktop\environment`. After that I tried below:

`virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.6 project_env`

and I received....:

`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '/usr/bin/python2.6'`

I dont understand whats going on. See below screenshot for extra info:
[image]

Comment: Do you have Python 2.6 already installed? If so, where in your filesystem is it installed?

Comment: A virtual environment references an already installed version of Python; it does not handle installing a new one.

Comment: On w32 you certainly don't have `/usr/bin/python2.6` — it's a Unix path. I believe you've copied it from some example. You have to adapt it to your path.

Comment: You clearly have not tried SO solutions, because they would have very quickly determined that you don't have a directory structure of `usr\bin\python2.6`, in the root of the current drive. If you do believe that you've tried solutions of SO, and they're not working, could you please provide the links to those, and I'll leave comment in those answers to tell their authors that you've found their solutions to be not working.

Comment: @TomDalton Do I need to install python 2.6 first? I dont have it installed

Comment: @Compo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv

Comment: Instead of posting a link with no explanation of why @TangerCity, can you please confirm that you have the following directory, `C:\usr\bin\python2.6`, which is what your command was using, _(because your current drive is `C:`)_. I'm going to assume by your previous comment, that you haven't even installed python 2.6, that you don't, _which further begs the question, why are you trying to use something your haven't got?_ If you haven't installed it, and you don't have that directory, then clearly you're going to get a message telling you that it cannot be found!

Comment: @Compo I can hereby confirm that I dont have that directory. I also dont that python 2.6 installed. I though that the virtualenv was going to install my new python 2.6.